# Equation ref's connected by "or"

Tags: cleveref

Using `cleveref`, running the command
`\cref{e1,e2}`
prints something along the lines of "eqs. (1) and (2)" or "eqs. (1)—(2)". What if I need to have and "or" instead of the "and", in a specific cross-reference? I expect I should use

```
\newcommand\crefpairconjunction{<conjunction>}
```

in the preamble, but I don't know how to make this change conditional instead of global, e.g. accessible through a command like `\cref[or]{e1,e2}`.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `\cref{e1} or \cref{e2}`? You actively don’t want an en dash between them here, since that means and.

Comment: I guess that would end up with "eq. (1) or eq. (2)", which has an extra "eq."  But `\cref{e1} or \ref{e2}` might fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

In a specific case you should use `\cref{e1} or~\cref{e2}` to leave no ambiguity to your reader.

If you insist, locally redefine the relevant macro.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\crefor}[1]{%
  {% start a group
   \providecommand{\crefpairconjunction}{}% initialize
   \renewcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{~or~}% want `or'
   \cref{#1}%
  }% end the group
}

\begin{document}

An equation
\begin{equation}\label{e1}
a=b
\end{equation}
and another one
\begin{equation}\label{e2}
c=d
\end{equation}
Now we reference \crefor{e1,e2}; also \cref{e1,e2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be clunky, but you could define a command that changes \crefpairconjunction when you want a different word inbetween.  You'd have to change it back after, however.

```
\newcommand\myConj[1]{\renewcommand\crefpairconjunction{#1}}

\begin{equation}\label{e1}
x^2n
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{e2}
2x^n
\end{equation}

\cref{e1,e2}
    
\myConj{ or~}
    
\cref{e1,e2}
```

[image]